# Online, Intermittent, Offline php ping script

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ping

Fairly new to server-side scripting in php here, so please bear w/ me:

**Question:**

1. How would I implement an Intermittent call?

---

**For Question 1:**

I've got things to work in terms of `Online` / `Offline`, however, I'm needing to implement an `Intermittent` call where if a 2nd device is down, the page will show an Intermittent status globally for the main device as well as showing that the 2nd device is offline but I'm not exactly sure how to go about doing this...

Here is the working online/offline script but has no Intermittent call below...

```
// CHECK CONNECTIVITY
class CheckDevice {

  // CHECK END USERS OS (Linux or Windows)
  public function myOS(){
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
      return true;

      return false;
    }

    public function ping($device_ip){
      if ($this->myOS()){
        if (!exec("ping -n 2 -w 1 ".$device_ip." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
          return true;
        } else {
          if (!exec("ping -q -c2 ".$device_ip." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
            return true;
          }

        return false;
    }
}

// IP of Device
$device_ip  = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';

// DEVICE CHECK
if ((new CheckDevice())->ping($device_ip))
  echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
                        <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
                            <div class="pic_bg"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p><b>DEVICE NAME</b></p>
                        <div class="status_online">Online</div>
                        <p class="span">No issues or outages to report...</p>';
else
  echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
                        <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
                            <div class="pic_bg"></div>
                        </div>
                        <p><b>DEVICE NAME</b></p>
                        <div class="status_offline">Offline</div>
                        <div class="status_offline_extended"></div>
                        <p class="span">Please be patient...</p>';
```

---

Script w/ more than 1 device where I'd like to have an Intermittent call whereas if device 2 goes down (or is offline), then device 1 would change it's state to Intermittent:

```
// CHECK CONNECTIVITY
    class CheckDevice {

      // CHECK END USERS OS (Linux or Windows)
      public function myOS(){
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
          return true;

          return false;
        }

        public function ping($device_ip){
          if ($this->myOS()){
            if (!exec("ping -n 2 -w 1 ".$device_ip." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
              return true;
            } else {
              if (!exec("ping -q -c2 ".$device_ip." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                return true;
              }

            return false;
        }
    }

    // CHECK CONNECTIVITY
    class CheckDevice2 {

      // CHECK END USERS OS (Linux or Windows)
      public function myOS(){
        if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === (chr(87).chr(73).chr(78)))
          return true;

          return false;
        }

        public function ping($device2_ip){
          if ($this->myOS()){
            if (!exec("ping -n 2 -w 1 ".$device2_ip." 2>NUL > NUL && (echo 0) || (echo 1)"))
              return true;
            } else {
              if (!exec("ping -q -c2 ".$device2_ip." >/dev/null 2>&1 ; echo $?"))
                return true;
              }

            return false;
        }
    }

    // IP of Device
    $device_ip  = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';
    $device2_ip = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx';

    // DEVICE CHECK
    if ((new CheckDevice())->ping($device_ip))
      echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
                            <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
                                <div class="pic_bg"></div>
                            </div>
                            <p><b>DEVICE NAME</b></p>
                            <div class="status_online">Online</div>
                            <p class="span">No issues or outages to report...</p>';
    else
      echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
                            <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
                                <div class="pic_bg"></div>
                            </div>
                            <p><b>DEVICE NAME</b></p>
                            <div class="status_offline">Offline</div>
                            <div class="status_offline_extended"></div>
                            <p class="span">Please be patient...</p>';

// DEVICE2 CHECK
        if ((new CheckDevice2())->ping($device2_ip))
          echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
                                <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
                                    <div class="pic_bg"></div>
                                </div>
                                <p><b>DEVICE2 NAME</b></p>
                                <div class="status_online">Online</div>
                                <p class="span">No issues or outages to report...</p>';
        else
          echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
                                <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
                                    <div class="pic_bg"></div>
                                </div>
                                <p><b>DEVICE2 NAME</b></p>
                                <div class="status_offline">Offline</div>
                                <div class="status_offline_extended"></div>
                                <p class="span">Please be patient...</p>';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like this should work for you:

```
 if ((new CheckDevice2())->ping($device2_ip))
    if ((new CheckDevice())->ping($device_ip))

        echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
        <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
            <div class="pic_bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p><b>DEVICE NAME</b></p>
        <div class="status_online">Online</div>
        <p class="span">No issues or outages to report...</p>';
        echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
        <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
            <div class="pic_bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p><b>DEVICE2 NAME</b></p>
        <div class="status_online">Online</div>
        <p class="span">No issues or outages to report...</p>';

    else

        echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
        <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
            <div class="pic_bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p><b>DEVICE NAME</b></p>
        <div class="status_offline">Offline</div>
        <div class="status_offline_extended"></div>
        <p class="span">Please be patient...</p>';
        echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
        <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
            <div class="pic_bg"></div>
        </div>
        <p><b>DEVICE2 NAME</b></p>
        <div class="status_online">Online</div>
        <p class="span">No issues or outages to report...</p>';

else
    echo "INTERMITENT";

    echo '<div class="status_wrapper">
    <div class="status_oo_wrapper">
        <div class="pic_bg"></div>
    </div>
    <p><b>DEVICE2 NAME</b></p>
    <div class="status_offline">Offline</div>
    <div class="status_offline_extended"></div>
    <p class="span">Please be patient...</p>';
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer - Thank you very much for your help on this.  It definitely got me going in the right direction!  The if/else statements is what threw me for a loop, but I have a better understanding of it now though due to your answer so thank you!